# Create a custom user tacking method on the wagtail?

Tags: django, analysis, wagtail

I have been followed [accordbox](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/wagtail-tutorials/) to create some models. For user activity analysis, I would like to save the user_id, restaurant_id, and time on visited RestaurantPage.
The logic is when get_context function in the Restaurant Model, it will use tracking function to save record in TrackUserRestaurant model.

The print function is used to check the request.user.id and restaurant.id.

But I can't get any new record on the TrackUserRestaurant model.

Did I misunderstand something?

I am new to Django and wagtail.

```
class RestaurantPage(Page)
    .... #other fields
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,
                                             editable=False)

    @property
    def restaurant_page(self):
        return self.get_parent().specific

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['restaurant_page'] = self.restaurant_page
        context['restaurant'] = self
        self.tracking(request)
        return context

    def tracking(self, request):
        current_user = request.user
        track = TrackUserRest
        track.user_id = 0
        track.restaurant_id = self.pk
        track.time = timezone.now()
        if request.user.id != None:
            print('user id:' + str(current_user.id))
            track.user = request.user.pk
        print('rest id:' + str(self.pk))
        return track.save(self)
```

```
class TrackUserRestaurant(models.Model):
    user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    restaurant_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('time', )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Restaurant Tracking system: user.id({}) viewed rest.id({}) at timezone.({})'.format(self.user_id,
                                           self.restaurant_id,
                                           self.time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The names used in your `tracking` method (`TrackUserRest`, `rest`) do not match your class definition (`TrackUserRestaurant`, `restaurant_id`)
2. The line `track = TrackUserRest` does not create a `TrackUserRest` object - it needs to be `track = TrackUserRest()`. As a result of this, the following lines are setting attributes on the `TrackUserRest` class, not a `TrackUserRest` object.
3. With this fixed, `track.save(self)` should become `track.save()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I Edited the attributes and, finally work with track.save().

May I ask more, if I want to update the view_count attribute of the RestautrantPage.
I added some code in the tracking fcuntion
`self.view_count = self.view_count+1
return super(RestuarantPage, self).save()`
It work with update the amount, but I am not sure that it is a right way?

Comment: It's best to post that as a new question. Setting fields like that on a Wagtail page model can get complicated, because of how Wagtail stores draft versions of pages - you'd need to ensure that publishing a new version doesn't overwrite the previous view count.